# How to do pagination and sorting on post table in cassandra database?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using cassandra v3.0 as my database

My Table Scheme is as below:

```
`CREATE TABLE db_name.post (
    postcreatedby timeuuid,
    contenttype text,
    createdat bigint,
    friendid timeuuid,
    posttype text,
    id timeuuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (postcreatedby, contenttype, createdat, friendid, posttype, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (contenttype ASC, createdat ASC, friendid ASC, posttype ASC, id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry`enter code here` = '99PERCENTILE';`
```

And I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT * from post WHERE postcreatedby = timeuuid  AND contenttype IN ('text', 'text') AND createdat < bigint AND friendid = timeuuid  AND posttype = 'text';
```

**And getting following Error:**

InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Clustering column "friendid" cannot be restricted (preceding column "createdat" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)"

**My question is:**

I need to use all columns for filtering the data and need to sort it as well. Here i am using 'createdAt' parameter to maintain sorting and pagination.

My problem is, if I will set createdAt as a last cluster key then I can use all columns for filtering as well but unable to sort that data. And if I will put the createdAt as before any parameter then I can not use last parameters as a filter.

Comment: for that query you would need (postcreatedby, contenttype, friendid, posttype, createdat, id)

Comment: You can do range search only on the last clustering column of your query...